# Is a smooth function on a line locally quasi-convex almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

1. Is a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}$ locally quasi-convex almost everywhere?
2. Is a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}$ locally convex at almost every local minimum?

---

1. True? I think the only counterexamples are at the local maxima.
2. Intuition tells me that it is true?

Comment: @6'whitemale Obviously for $\mathbb R^n$ the first statement is not true. I am considering the $\mathbb R$ case for now. But I will be very appreciate if you could extend the discussions to $\mathbb R^n$. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure 2. fails. Consider the function

$$\tag 1 f(x) = \exp [-1/(x(1-x))]\cdot[2 + \sin (\,1/(x(1-x))^2\,)]$$

for $x\in (0,1),$ $f=0$ everywhere else. Then $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R),$ $f>0$ on $(0,1),$ and the support of $f$ is $[0,1].$ Clearly $f$ has a local minimum at both $0$ and $1.$ A slightly messy, but not too awful, computation shows $f'$ is both positive and negative in any neighborhood $0,$ and in any neighborhood $1.$ Thus $f$ is not locally convex in any neighborhood of those points.

This example can of course be transferred to any bounded interval $(a,b).$

Now suppose $K$ is a Cantor set of positive measure. Then the complement of $K$ is a pairwise disjoint countable union of open intervals. All but two of these intervals is bounded; let $(a_n,b_n), n=1,2,\dots$ be these bounded intervals. Then every point of $K$ is either one of the endpoints $a_n,b_n,$ or is the limit of a subsequence of these endpoints.

On each $(a_n,b_n)$ we construct $f_n$ as in $(1).$ If we choose small enough positive constants $c_n,$ then the function $f=\sum c_nf_n$ will be smooth on $\mathbb R.$ This $f$ is positive on each $(a_n,b_n)$ and is $0$ everywhere else. Thus each point of $K$ is a local minimum of $f.$ But because of the oscillation of each $f_n'$ near $a_n,b_n,$ $f$ fails to be locally convex at each $x\in K.$